# How to run "terraform state mv" commands in the Terraform Enterprise/Cloud?

Tags: terraform

I'm in the process of a Terraform code refactoring in which some resources are moved to a module A and a module B into a submodule of A and I'm now getting this error in Terraform Enterprise:

```
Error: Provider configuration not present

To work with
module.account-baseline.module.iam-policy.aws_iam_role.ops_role
its original provider configuration at module.account-baseline.provider.aws is
required, but it has been removed. This occurs when a provider configuration
is removed while objects created by that provider still exist in the state.
Re-add the provider configuration to destroy
module.account-baseline.module.iam-policy.aws_iam_role.ops_role,
after which you can remove the provider configuration again.
```

I've tried in my playground account using a local Terraform state to run "terraform state mv" commands moving the module into a sub-module and it works, but I don't know how to apply this state change to Terraform Enterprise.

Any help would be more than welcome, thanks in advance!

Comment: If it works with your local state, then you can push it to the remote state after modifications.

Comment: Thanks, I've got that somehow working but it's a manual process and I need to do this over a few dozen workspaces. I'm now trying to automate it somehow.

Comment: I wish there was a way to have some sort of pre-apply hook where I could put a migration script that runs the state altering commands before the apply/run.